# c# Dynamic panel on mouse

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, panel

I am making a N*M size SUDOKU game. Every number are on a button.
When the program start all button is empty and I would like if I click to a button it is make a little panel on it with buttons for each number to choose one.

```
    private void adatB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        int[] hely = button.Tag.ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
        Panel szamok = new Panel
        {
            Location = MousePosition,
            Size = new Size(100, 100)
        };
        Controls.Add(szamok);
        TableLayoutPanel minitabla = new TableLayoutPanel
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ColumnCount = szorzat,
            RowCount = szorzat,
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < szorzat; i++)
        {
            minitabla.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            minitabla.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        }
        szamok.Controls.Add(minitabla);
        Button[,] szamokB = new Button[meret[0], meret[1]];
        int d = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < meret[0]; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < meret[1]; j++)
            {
                szamokB[i, j] = new Button();
                szamokB[i, j].Tag= hely[0]+","+hely[1];
                szamokB[i, j].Text = d.ToString();
                szamokB[i, j].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                szamokB[i, j].Click += szamokB_Click;
                minitabla.Controls.Add(szamokB[i, j], i, j);
                d++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void szamokB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        int[] hely = button.Tag.ToString().Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
        adatB[hely[0], hely[1]].Text = button.Text;
    }
```

The problem with it when I click a button the pane isn't created.
meret[0] variable is the N, meret[1] is M, adatB is the arry of buttons with the positons in tag.
And If I choosed the number how can I close that panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should calculate the mouseposition correctly.

From MSDN:

> Gets the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates.

You should use something like this:

```
Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - this.Location.X, MousePosition.Y - this.Location.Y)
```

You will probably need this, to bring your panel to the front:

```
Controls.Add(szamok);
szamok.BringToFront();
```

To close the panel you can store the chooser panel and you can remove it from the controls later, use something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Panel myPanel = null;

    private void adatB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        Panel szamok = new Panel
        {
            Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - this.Location.X, MousePosition.Y - this.Location.Y),
            Size = new Size(100, 100)
        };

        if (this.myPanel != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(this.myPanel);
        }
        this.myPanel = szamok;

        Controls.Add(szamok);
        szamok.BringToFront();

        ...
    }

    private void szamokB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.myPanel != null)
        {
            this.Controls.Remove(this.myPanel);
            this.myPanel = null;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```